# Populate Sqlite3 column with data from Python list using for loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite3 in Python by using a for loop to iterate through all the items in a list and populate a column with that data. My code below will hopefully shed some light on the problem:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

test_run = ['tommy', 'olga', 'peter', 'lulu']


con = lite.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test1;')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test1(symbol TEXT); ')
for i in test_run:
    name = i
    print name

cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(?)',name)

with con:

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test1")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
     print row
```

I apologize if this is very basic, but I have just learned Python and this is my first time using SQL. When I print name it seems like this should work but when using fetchall to see what is being populated it appears as:

```
(u't',)
(u'o',)
(u'm',)
(u'm',)
(u'y',)
(u'o',)
(u'l',)
```

I have read a lot of the answers here and this would seem to be the correct way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I can identify following issues in your code.

1. The `cur.executemany` is not in the loop.
2. There is only one parameter to bind in the `insert` query. No need to use `cur.executemany`.
3. When binding string parameter to a query, you should convert your string to `tuple`.

I think the correct code might look like this -

```
for i in test_run:
    name = (i,)
    print i
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(?)", name)
```

Also use `con.commit()` after the insert query or you can't get the inserted rows after application termination. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yours should work, but retaining the executemany is good practice for large datasets.